# Rewriterule -> 500 internal error with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, internal-server-error

I tried everything for my problem, but nothing works.

I'm not familiar with regex, but I did my best.

Here is the code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^series/([A-Z]+)?$ series.php?code=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^exercices/([A-Z]+)-([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?$ exercices.php?code=$1&serie=$2&question=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

# Remove php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect to 404 if url is not correct
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.test.com/404 [L]

# Errors
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.test.com/404
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.test.com/
ErrorDocument 500 https://www.test.com/
```

With that, I have a beautiful 500 internal error...

I've really did some research, but I'm still stuck.

Can someone help me please ?
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I have this in the log but I don't know what it means : Invalid command '.....', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 1):

I just added " **/?** " just before the " **$** " sign, and it's working :

```
RewriteRule ^series/([A-Z]+)/?$ /series.php?code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^exercices/([A-Z]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ /exercices.php?code=$1&serie=$2&question=$3 [L]
```

I hope it will help for people who have the same issue.

Thanks.